# Unicode has "combining characters". How to use them?

Tags: unicode, composition, ascii-art

with combining characters one can use 2 unicode characters at single location, creating a composition of two graphics. I'm thinking about simple ascii art, I would need to first use, as wikipedia says "SQUARE WITH HORIZONTAL FILL" ▤, and then on top of that, the letter "A". How to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure there are characters that can combine arbitrary other characters. Instead, I thought "combining characters" were characters that intend to modify other characters, like putting *themselves* on top of that other character. I really have no idea though.

Comment: [SQUARE WITH HORIZONTAL FILL](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a4/index.htm) is **not** a combining character, as you can see `Combine: 0` in the properties. [Combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) are the ones that are supposed to put on another like [Å (U+00C5) which has another representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character#Comparing_precomposed_and_decomposed_characters): A (U+0041) + [combining ring above (U+030A)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/030a/index.htm)

Comment: It is not arbitrary, it is the text rendering engine that combines them into a single glyph.  It knows about the typographic rules in the current UI language.  Quite unlikely that it does what you want it to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is possible with the method you describe is a kind of abuse of diacritical marks. Fell free to play around a bit with it using following [demo](http://demo.danielmclaren.com/2015/diacriticism/) ( http://demo.danielmclaren.com/2015/diacriticism/ ).

Below some screenshots of the Unicode code I have got from the demo above:

[image: Claudio.txt content copied to a terminal]  Claudio.txt content copied to a terminal

[image: Claudio.txt displayed in gedit]  Claudio.txt displayed in gedit

[image: Claudio.txt displayed in SciTE]  Claudio.txt displayed in SciTE

Sorry, but I don't know at the moment why exactly the representation of same underlying Unicode text is looking different in SciTE.

Here the HexCode of the Claudio.txt file:

[image: Claudio.txt displayed as hex code in GHex]  Claudio.txt displayed as hex code in GHex

and here the Unicode copied/pasted to the stackoverflow answer editor box:

C̱̙̳̲͇͉̄̄̚l̝̩̩̝̺̠͞ā̝͉̩̟͆u̻͈̘̞̪̅̿d̝̄̅͆̚i͇̙͈̎̚o̘̟̎̄̄̎

As you have to be able to show ASCII art in a terminal I assume that there is no way to overlay two arbitrary Unicode characters for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Depending from the application or browser there are two ways to use the [Unicode Combining Diacritical Marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks):

- With ā (a macron) as example, you may try to type in the 'a' first
  followed by the decimal code & #772;
- or **ALT+** (it must be the + from the numeric keypad) followed by the
  hexadecimal code 0304 (i.e U+0304).

In some cases you can type in the combining diacritical mark first, followed by the 'a' or any other leading letter.

Comment: For example in Ubuntu Text Editor type ` x CONTROL SHIFT U 364 SPACE` and you will get an x with an e on top of it.

Comment: a first and  ̄  next, in some cases  ̄   first and a next. What the heck? There must be a standardized way of doing it. It's not about guessing, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Square with Horizontal Fill U+25A4.

Combining Latin Small Letter A U+0363.

To obtain Square with Horizontal Fill topped by 'a' ▤ͣ
in Ubuntu Text Edit, type

SHIFT CONTROL U 25A4
SHIFT CONTROL U 363 SPACE

Combining Latin Capital Letter A does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is just for the mac users, but I came across this question and had no way of attempting to do this myself, I found this afterward for actually writing unicode characters without having to fool around: https://www.webnots.com/how-to-use-unicode-hex-input-method-in-mac/

tldr; There's a keyboard input encoding for Unicode Character input in Mac OS in the same area that you would enable other keyboard layouts for other languages. It's under Other at the bottom.